# How to use the 'setMyViewController' in iPhone'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. In my program, there are several controller class. However, I dont' know how to handle them and switch the control right between different view controller classes. I read some code from the apple website. Can anyone explain to me? Thank you very much.

```
// I create a view controller called 'MyViewController' 
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");

    MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; // what meaning of this statement
    [self setMyViewController:aViewController]; // can I set in other class
    [aViewController release];

    UIView *controllersView = [myViewController view]; // what is it use?
    [window addSubview:controllersView];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// what meaning of this statement
MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

This block will load your main view controller from the .xib file. Do you know about Interface Builder, you can set the View of the ViewController in the MyViewController.xib and then load it using this line

```
[self setMyViewController:aViewController]; // can I set in other class
```

Theoretically, you can set a ViewController in anywhere you have viewControlelr as a property. However, the code here means that you set the aViewController as your root view controller in the program, the first view controller you will see when you open the program.

```
   UIView *controllersView = [myViewController view]; // what is it use?
    [window addSubview:controllersView];
```

These 2 lines will make the view visible and can be seen by the user. you add the subview of your root view controller into the main window, and then show it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I want to display several page, and it contains the tab, table, page with button, what type of project should I created? I mean the File-> New Project -> ??. I use the navigation-based windows and create the new class selected by the windows based type, am I right? If not, what class should I create? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do something like music application on ipod or ipod app in iphone, you should go with tab bar application. If you want to have a hierarchy, you can go with navigation-based application. I don't get what you mean yet. You mean you are using : [self.navigationController pushViewController:], is it right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the topic is a little bit out of this one, so I open a new post to discuss the question. Would you mind to take a look and give me some suggestions? Thank you very much. Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288426/how-to-pass-the-control-or-find-the-flow-of-the-this-iphone-application